# C# one statusStrip for multi tabs?

Tags: c#, tabpage, statusstrip

My form has multi tab pages, can I use 1 statusStrip for all those tabs? Because when I change from tab_page1 to tab_page2, the statusStrip at the bottom of my form disappeared. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the statusStrip within the tab page? If so, then you should move it outside the tab page.

Comment: yeah, I moved it outside and it worked, my bad. Thanks, raRaRa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `StatusStrip` is located within a `TabPage`. It should be on `Form` along with `TabControl` so that all `tabs` in `TabControl` and other controls can use it.

Comment: yes, I put it in the tabPage1, silly me! Thanks for your answer.